# How can I add a class for td in reference to two columns

Tags: php, css, class, html-table

I have a render of row of database

```
echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
echo "<tr> <th>ID</th> <th>First Name</th> <th>Last Name</th> <th></th> <th></th></tr>";

// loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

    // echo out the contents of each row into a table
    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['tex1'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['tex2'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['tex3'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['tex4'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['tex5'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['tex6'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['tex7'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['tex8'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['tex9'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['tex10'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Edit</a></td>';
    echo '<td><a href="delete.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Delete</a></td>';
    echo "</tr>"; 
} 

// close table>
echo "</table>";
```

And in the tex1 is a date, my problem is for a class for tr, when the tex2 is empty and the date of tex1 is older than 30 days, tr have class red, the date of tex1 is inserted manually,how can I do to change the class on the basis of this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood what you wanted properly but I'll give it a shot. You want to add a class ("red") to the , whenever the condition is met that either the date is older than 30 days old (tex1) or the First Name is empty (tex2).

```
echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
echo "<tr> <th>ID</th> <th>First Name</th> <th>Last Name</th> <th></th> <th></th></tr>";

// loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

    // echo out the contents of each row into a table
    // I assume since you're just printing it out, the date is a String
    // So first convert it to a timestamp
    $date = strtotime($row['tex1']);
    // Determine the difference, I'm doing it this way to make it easy for you to understand
    $days = 60*60*24*30; // 30 days
    if (empty($row['tex2']) || time()-$date > $days) {
        echo '<tr>';
    } else {
        echo '<tr class="red">';
    }
    echo '<td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['tex1'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['tex2'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['tex3'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['tex4'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['tex5'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['tex6'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['tex7'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['tex8'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['tex9'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['tex10'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Edit</a></td>';
    echo '<td><a href="delete.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Delete</a></td>';
    echo "</tr>"; 
} 

// close table>
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check for the conditions what you have mentioned in your question. And this can be done like this.

```
 if(strtotime($row['tex1']) + 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 < time() && $row['tex2'] =="") {
       $class="class='red'";
 } else {
       $class= "";
 }

 echo "<tr $class>";// id condition satisfies, class='red' will get echo, else echo will be null.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a conditional when writing the  element:

```
echo '<tr'.
    ( ((strtotime($row['tex1']) < strtotime('30 days ago'))
      && (empty($row['tex2']))) ? ' class="red"' : '').
'>';
```

Comment: thanks, this is what i want, but another question how i render the date European Dd/Mm/Yy and not Mm/Dd/Yy?

Comment: Well, that's another question. Please mark this one as answered and post another question if you have further issues with your script if they do not concern the "how to insert a class" issue.

Comment: I suppose you are looking for something like: date_format(date_create($row['tex1']),"d/m/Y")